# rebuild the signature of a function knowing only its name and argument list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, traits, overloading

I am writing some macros that take a function name and do some actions, one of which is getting its signature through `decltype` and use it as a template parameter.

I want to extend these macros to support overloaded functions. My idea is to make them take an additional argument specifying the arguments list but not the complete signature, since two function overloads cannot be different for only the return type. The problem arises when I attempt to rebuild the complete signature of the function as I did in the non-overloaded case with `decltype`: how do I guess the return type?

I've tried with `result_of`, but with no luck:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double f(int, int);
int f(int, int, int);

int main(){
    cout<<typeid(result_of<decltype(&f)(int,int, int)>::type).name()<<endl;
}
```

The snippet works if `double f(int, int)` is commented out. I understand that this is because within `decltype` it is unknown what of the two overloads to pick. Normally, one would prepend a dummy cast to a signature matching the desired overload, but that would mean that you know ahead the return type, hence all this stuff would be useless.

Is there a way to solve this problem, or do I have to enforce the user to specify the full signature in the macro?

EDIT:
Basically, I have these two macros:

```
//add a member function as a method
#define addmethod2(stringname, methodname)      fields[#stringname]=method_helper<decltype(&hold_type::methodname), &hold_type::methodname>::worker
#define addmethod(methodname)                   addmethod2(methodname, methodname)
```

I want to add a third, `addmethod3`, which takes *only* the arguments list (if it was the complete signature with return type, it would be trivial), in order to select the correct member function overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
template<typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
using NoDeduce = typename identity<T>::type;

template<typename T>
using Identity = T;

template<typename ...P, typename R>
Identity<R(P...)> *get_f(R f(NoDeduce<P>...)) {
  return f;
}
```

Then you can say

```
auto *f1 = get_f<int, int, int>(f);
auto *f2 = get_f<int, int>(f);
```

Comment: @LorenzoPistone that's an "alias declaration" and when you make it a template it becomes an "alias template". "Identity<T>" is type "T". That frees you from having to write "R(*get_f(R f(typename identity<P>::type...)))(P...);`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `decltype` and make a call expression: `decltype(f(0, 0, 0))`. When the arguments are types that you can't easily provide instances of of (unlike `int`), use `std::declval` to fake it:

```
decltype(f(std::declval<int>(), std::declval<int>(), std::declval<int>()))
```

Comment: I cannot do this. The user passes the arguments list as a packed sequence in a single argument of the macro (this is the only natural way I could think of, and the only worth my efforts to implement, otherwise I give up), and then I have to way to split it and insert all those `declval`

Comment: @LorenzoPistone Can you edit your question and elaborate those requirements? It may still be doable.